# It seems we have a vandal loose

Tags: discussion

We have all probably seen mysterious downvotes occasionally, but recently there seems to be a more persistant vandal on the loose.  Here are three answers I wrote yesterday and today that all got silently downvoted for no apparent reason:

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/87165/4512
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/87252/4512
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/87335/4512

(Note that the first two are separate answers to the same question)

When you say something controversial or against someone's religiously held beliefs, you sometimes get a silent downvote.  In those cases, at least you can take a reasonable guess you stepped on someone's toes who didn't leave a comment because they didn't want to admit the downvote was for personal reasons.

However, these three posts aren't like that.  I think it's quite clear someone is going around downvoting for spite, retribution, or just plain vandalism.  Has anyone else experienced this?

I don't care about the -6 rep.  I do care that the time I put into writing answers is not wasted by pushing those answers artifically down the list where less people will see them or others may think they are wrong or unreliable.

### Added:

Here are more:

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/87336/4512
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/29224/4512

Comment: Somebody dislikes PIC?

Comment: Ahh, well that's what I get for trying to figure things out on my phone. My apologies.

Comment: Funny aside: this thread is the only recent one on the meta with -6. Interesting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Again, *I* can't view who voted for you either. With *this* scale of voting it is difficult to identify patterns of abuse because it is a very small signal in the noise of all the votes you have received.

To add a lousy analogy, it is like a Wal-Mart calling the police because someone swiped a few packs of gum. The police would punish the perpetrator if they could be found, and they may have someone they suspect, but nothing that they could act on. The police don't condone the action, but they aren't going to bring in the K-9 unit and their best detectives for a few packs of gum.

I still feel like I have put in quite a bit more effort to investigate than this probably warranted. I also still feel that you are overreacting quite a bit. I may have a lead or two if this turns into a *trend*, but I don't have anything that I can act on.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea how easy or not it is for you to look into such things.  I was also asking whether anyone else had experienced this recently.  Since nobody answered, apparently not.

Comment: @OlinLathrop Higher rep users will occasionally pick up a fan boy or opposite. I think you have had both now. We keep looking into it.

Comment: @OlinLathrop It's happened to me. Still happens every now and then, a series of 3 or 4 downvotes, often even on very old and unrelated answers. It's someone's way of working out their day's stress, best ignored.

Answer (score 2):

I had a couple of unexplained down votes in one day about two weeks ago. They occurred within probably 30 mins of each other and I believe they were the 1st votes cast on each question despite them being negative.

If there were a way if seeing who was active on the site would their stats have shown -1 if I'd have visited their reputation profile?

Comment: You could take a guess [see this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128074/are-votes-really-anonymous/128080#128080) but it'd only be practical if you had a few people in mind, they weren't otherwise very active rep wise and even then you'd be guessing it was your answer and not something else.